# Python - get the last line in a file list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import operator
import os
import sys
import time
import glob
SimServer = '11.1.1.1' 
user = 'aaa'
passwd = 'bbb' 
simDir = '/path/to/dir' 
simFtp = FTP() 
print ("\n[INFO]: Connecting to FTP server:\n") 
print (simFtp.connect('11.1.1.1')) 
print ("\n[INFO]: login with user name and password\n") 
print (simFtp.login (user,passwd)) 
print ("\n[INFO]: Switching to the relevant directory\n") 
print (simFtp.cwd(simDir)) 
list = simFtp.retrlines('LIST') 
print ("bye")
```

I have a variable (named list) that include a file list from ftp server

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 13:23 290
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 22:26 290
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 14 11:10 291
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 27 21:50 292
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 30 09:57 292
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 03 09:17 293
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 06 15:07 293
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 14 15:25 294
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 25 08:31 294
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 25 07:26 294
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 01 11:28 295
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 02 12:31 320
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 02 11:29 320
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 04 15:22 320
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 11 15:52 320
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 15 11:41 321
drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 16 15:41 321
```

The list will change from time to time and I will always want `cd` to the last directory, 321 in that case.

Comment: perhaps not an option but, what about you create that list in reverse order and pick the first?

Comment: is the `flist` variable really a string containing lines?

Answer (score 3):

Since the question says -

> get last line in a file list

If the variable `flist` you have is like -

```
["drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 13:23 290",
 "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 22:26 290",
 "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 14 11:10 291",
 "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 27 21:50 292",
 "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 30 09:57 292",
 "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 03 09:17 293",
 ...]
```

Then you can get the file name of the last file in the above `flist` as -

```
flist[-1].split()[-1]
>> '321'
```

Comment: This is same as the other answer.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that, the focus of your answers looked like - `os.chdir()`

Comment: good one. but as you can see in my first post the directories are not separated by "," and i also need to convert them to a list right?

Comment: they are separated into different lines right? - the line - `flist[-1].split()` splits the line based on space characters (even taking multiple space characters into consideration.

Comment: i just want to tail that the 'list' saved in a variable from the first place and not as a list

Comment: know i notice that the list is just a print to the console and was not save at all )= is there any way to save it?

Comment: yes, you will have to use that exact code, where you want to get the last folder inside your complete code. This is not a complete code

Comment: the complete code:
`from ftplib import FTP
import operator
import os
import sys
import time 
import glob

SimServer = '11.1.1.1'
user = 'aaa'
passwd = 'bbb'
simDir = '/path/to/dir'
simFtp = FTP()

print ("\n[INFO]: Connecting to FTP server:\n")
print (simFtp.connect('11.1.1.1'))
print ("\n[INFO]: login with user name and password\n")
print (simFtp.login (user,passwd))
print ("\n[INFO]: Switching to the relevant directory\n")
print (simFtp.cwd(simDir))
list = simFtp.retrlines('LIST')
print ("bye")`

Comment: use `lastfolder = list[-1].split()[-1]` after defining the list , and then use `simFtp.cwd(simDir + "/" + lastfolder)`

Answer (score 2):

New to Python? You'll appreciate the way it lets you index into lists: negative indices just wrap around the back.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[-1]
3
>>> a[1:-1]
[3, 1]
```

In this case, you probably need to split the directory listing into lines (unless you can get the directory listing in a shorter format, like `ls | tail -n 1`):

```
lines = flist.splitlines()
lastline = lines[-1]
lastdir = lastline.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extracting the path from the input list**

```
>>> file_list = ["drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 13:23 290",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 06 22:26 290",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 14 11:10 291",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 27 21:50 292",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Apr 30 09:57 292",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 03 09:17 293",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 06 15:07 293",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 14 15:25 294",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 25 08:31 294",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 May 25 07:26 294",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 01 11:28 295",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 02 12:31 320",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 02 11:29 320",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 04 15:22 320",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 11 15:52 320",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 15 11:41 321",
... "drwxr-xr-x    3 10140    10140        4096 Jun 16 15:41 321 "]
>>> filename = file_list[-1].split()[-1]
>>> filename
'321'
```

Comment: @Llopis all `os` module functions methods deals with local operating system, so an answer is no.

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszR. what I thought

Comment: @Assafbaruch The statement *ALWAYS want cd to the last directory* needs more clarity. Where are you running the script from

Comment: @Assafbaruch Are you trying to cd from the local machine to the ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

If  the name of the folder is filename you can `cd` to the folder of the ftp server with:

```
>>> ftp.cwd('filename')
```

If ftp is

```
from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('ftp.server')
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can deploy your python code on a remote machine, then you can use os.chdir() to change dir. or you can deploy your code on a locate machine and use python library: Paramiko to control remote machine, you can find some idea in this page: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/sftp.html

but this two methods both use file_list[-1].split()[-1] to get last line